# Hierarchy navigating viewcontroller to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, hierarchy, uistoryboardsegue

I have 3 viewcontrollers with a navigation controller.

I am able to go from the first to the second using a push segue, but I can't go from the second to the third.

It says the view is not in the window hierarchy. I have been googling it, but can't find anything I can comprehend. I haven't messed with the appdelegate at all, and seems like that is the answer, but do not know how to implement.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"secondToThird" sender: self];
```

I am using the performSegueWithIdentifier for first to second, but doesn't work from the second to third. I don't have any other relevant information about the going from vc to vc besides setting it up in the interface builder.

Comment: Is your third VC is connected by multiple segues or from multiple places (from storyboard and from code with `prepareForSegue`)?

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: 2014-02-03 17:07:40.120 VideoEmailApp[4324:907] Warning: Attempt to present <ThirdViewController: 0x1f10a740> on <UINavigationController: 0x1e545b30> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: You need to fully describe, or post an image of your storyboard. There's something wrong with your setup there.

Comment: http://s1370.photobucket.com/user/sean_cleveland1/media/Untitled_zpsc9022523.png.html?o=0

Comment: Can you show prepare for segue method in your second vc?

Comment: I know the basic method is: '-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
 
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegueID"]) {
 
      // do something here...
 
   }
}' But how do I use it for the hierarchy?